# asp.net bind business objects boolean properties to checkboxlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, reflection

I have 7 different classes and each have multiple boolean properties. I am trying to work out a way to dynamically bind these properties to a checkboxlist.

Ideally I could have one checkboxlist control then based on another selection I can bind any of the 7 different class objects boolean properties to the one checknoxlist control. Some of these objects have more than just boolean properties.

I have seen some examples around of using reflection to bind controls to business objects but I am not 100% sure if this is the right approach in my case.

Is something like this possible? Or will I have to define 7 different checkboxlists and manually create list items for each of the properties in my business object?

Comment: Do each of the 7 classes have the same boolean properties? If so, just use an interface and specify a bind from that interface. Other than that reflection is probably your best bet.

Comment: They each have different boolean properties... How would I be able to use an interface to do this when binding? Is there a way to label the checkboxes with the name of the property?